# how to implement modal by using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am using **modal** concept of bootstrap in my **html** file. In modal i am entering data after clicking on save this data should be displayed in  html page where modal is called. By using which function i can include or display this data in html page.

Comment: @alex-mcmillan Why did you remove the angularjs tag? Integrating Bootstrap with AngularJS is different from using Bootstrap with plain JavaScript.

Comment: @Hoa my apologies, there was no mention of AngularJS in the question.  Feel free to put it back if you feel that is more correct.

Comment: are you using angularjs ?, share your code. so that we know how far you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sqCwDUEzLSWW6ykst7rY?p=preview) for your reference

The basic idea is that you can pass an object from a modal back to the controller which opens the modal with `close()` as follows

```
$uibModalInstance.close($ctrl.modal);
```

Then in the parent controller, you can obtain the object as follows

```
modalInstance.result.then(function(modal) {
  $ctrl.modal = modal;
}, function () {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume bootstrap "modal" style class used in the code to show popup from parent page. Here, JavaScript /jquery would help to update the content from modal div to other div in the same page.

Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/AMVijay/f46qLn8L/1/

HTML Content with Bootstrap and JQuery:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Modal Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="modalSaveButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Java Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#modalSaveButton").click(function() {
    var fullName = $("#inputFirstName").val() + " " + $("#inputLastName").val();
    console.log("Full Name :: " + fullName);
    $("#inputName").val(fullName);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
  });
});
```

Comment: By using javascript i want to implement.